# PHP how to redirect the page to a different PHP file?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I couldn't find much help while I was looking for my answer that's the reason for the question on here.

Basically I have this bit of code :

```
<a href="manage/10000' . $user["user_id"] . ' " class="user_grop">More Info</span></a>
```

now how is it possible to get what I am passing ?

Do I make a php file called manage.php ? if so what makes it so that it looks at manage.php ? and then get it through $_GET but how is it possible ?

I am not sure how to go about it so I would appreciate any of yours suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: If the code isn't yours and doesn't use a framework, look at the `.htaccess` file on the project base directory. There should be a rewrite containing that link. something like `RewriteRule ^manage/([0-9]+)$ /manage.php?user=$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can have two possible solutions:

1. By creating `manage.php` file and passing query string to it.

Your code for the link will like this:

```
<a href="manage.php?user_id=' . $user["user_id"] . ' " class="user_grop">More Info</span></a>
```

Now on `manage.php` page, you can access user_id like this:

```
<?php $user_id = $_GET["user_id"]; ?>
```

2. Using `.htaccess`, create `.htaccess` file and put the code below in it. `.htaccess` file must be placed in same `dir` where your `index.php` file is.

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] </IfModule>`

Now you can access your query strings on `index.php` file using  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` global variable.

```
<a href="manage/10000/' . $user["user_id"] . ' " class="user_grop">More Info</span></a>
```

Your link to access page must look like above `note the / after 10000 else user_id will get merge with 10000`

Chatting session was performed for the question, [view chat transcript here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/125808)

Comment: when I try using the .htaccess it's redirecting me to index.php file

Comment: You can use both `$_GET` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on your `index.php` page to access variable.

Comment: it's routing perfect and this is how the link looks like :http://localhost/users/manage/10000/12

Comment: but manage.php is not getting called at all

Comment: You will have to use `$value = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  then `$valArr = explode("/",$value);` now all your values must be stored to `$valArr` and you can access them like `$valArr[0]`

Comment: if you want to go with `manage.php` way, your link must look like `<a href="manage.php?user_id=<?php echo $user['user_id]; ?>">More Info</a>` Now you will have to use `$_GET['user_id']` to get value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125808/discussion-between-mistersuraj-and-jomin-george94).

Answer (score 2):

You need a routing-engine to manage that type of url.

There are many framework that include routing. The most used is Symfony http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: he only needs htaccess and mod_rewrite on.

Comment: i think routing-engine is better for application mantenience

Answer (score 2):

The general syntax would be as follows:

```
http://domain_name.com/script.php?parameter1=value&parameter2=value
```

In your case you would have the following assuming that your parameter is
**user_id**:

```
<a href="manage.php?user_id='.$user["user_id"].'" class="user_grop">More Info</span></a>
```

In PHP you would use `$_GET['user_id']` to fetch the passed value

```
$userID = $_GET['user_id'];
```

By including these lines in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^manage\/([0-9]+)$ manage.php?user_id=$1
```

You could reach the same page with the following syntax:

```
http://domainname/manage/2313
```

Comment: can I do it without explicitly including the extension (.php) ?

Comment: Currently I have this rewrite :

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: Yes you can, see the update

Comment: So I have made changes to my .htaccess , to this

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^manage\/([0-9]+)$ manage.php?user_id=$1

Comment: try it out, that should work

Comment: when I click on my link I do get the id however the link is like this : http://localhost/users/manage.php?user_id=33

Comment: shouldn't replace it to :

Comment: http://localhost/cars/admin/manage/user_id/33

Comment: the link can only be like this: http://localhost/cars/admin/manage/33

Comment: or like this http://localhost/cars/admin/manage.php?user_id=33

Comment: localhost/cars/admin/manage/33 this would have been perfect but not happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125807/discussion-between-cristian-and-jomin-george94).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to say that you need to route to a different php file manage.php and get the passed variable from the previous page then either you can modify the link to

```
"manage.php?val=10000".$user["user_id"]
```

and then use $_GET to get the passed variable

Or else you can keep the same url use .htaccess to route your request to  manage.php?val=$1

or else in frameworks like codeigniter you have routes file where you can define your route.

Comment: I didn't want to show the extension (.php)

Comment: Then you should use htaccess to route your request

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: yes you can use rewriterule to route to manage.php without exposing .php extension and the parameter key, typically the way you want the url to be